# How to show sqlite datas in a textview?

Tags: iphone

My name is NipinVarma,I would want to know about some errors in my iphone application.I am doing a bible application for a client,i almost complete the functionality s of the application,like authentication ,UI etc etc.sqlite is used for the database of the bible,i want to display the bible sql database in a textview.But i already done this with a tableview controller,every verses and genisis are displayed in tableview according to my needs through array count.My need is to display this in a textview when we open that page for reading bible.here i put my code that gives me the correct input in tableview.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    BibleIphoneAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BibleIphoneAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return appDelegate.biblearray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:12.0];
    // Set up the cell
    tbl.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    BibleIphoneAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BibleIphoneAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    bible *jesus = (bible *)[appDelegate.biblearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setText:jesus.chapterNo];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = jesus.verseNumber;
    cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0];
    return cell;
```

Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use didSelectRowAtIndexPath of UITableViewDelegate:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    [self pushChildViewControllerForRow:row animated:YES];
}
```

Then in pushChildViewControllerForRow you can do something like:

```
-(void)pushChildViewControllerForRow:(NSUInteger)row animated:(BOOL)flag {
     if (chapterViewController==nil) {
            self.chapterViewController = [[ChapterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChapterViewController" bundle:nil];
        [navigationController pushViewController:chapterViewController animated:flag];
        // and here you will need to populate chapterViewController with data extracted from your sqlite database
}
```

ChapterViewController might be similar to:

```
@interface ChapterViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;
-(void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

Hope you got an idea.

Comment: but sir i didnt want any tableview functionality,just want to display it in a textview when a page is open.

Comment: @Nipinvarma, when user chooses which page he/she wants to be open, he/she presses raw in your table. Then didSelectRowAtIndexPath got called. Last loads ChapterViewController, pushes it into navigation stack and populates it with data of the page. ChapterViewController is nothing more than UITextView which you want.

Comment: but actual functionalty is when the user makes his signup correctly it atomatically navigate through this bible page which we want to display it in textview.it should be in viewdidload method.

Comment: sorry sir,I think this a communication problem with us,ok my need is to show bibledata base in a textview not in a tableview.above code is to display database in a tableview controer right?