# Sqlite in a textview

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to display a sqlite values in a textview?I have made it in a tableviewcontroller,but i am not able to display the same in a textview. appdelegate.biblearray is the array that holds the sqldata.I have the same qustion in another forom .please look at this link for that question [here is the link]: [How to show sqlite datas in a textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595844/how-to-show-sqlite-datas-in-a-textview)

Please help me to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
bible *jesus = (bible *)[appDelegate.biblearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

use string variable or the type of value that biblearray contains

```
NSString *str = [appDelegate.biblearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

For only displaying in textview, you dont need to use class object jesus.

Comment: but we have to put this in viewdidload method to show it ijn textview,bez user have to read it when the page opens

Comment: As per your code this line is in cellForRowAtIndex path so this will be called with ViewDidLoad.

Comment: (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 BibleIphoneAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BibleIphoneAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSString *str = [appDelegate.biblearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 _bibleDesciption.text = str;

}
indexpath undeclared error

Comment: you cannot use indexPath in viewDidLoad because this is variable of UITableView method.